# Serializing with JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization, uwp

I need serialize couple properties. I use Json serializer from NewtonSoft

My code:

```
   [DataContract]
public class ImageManipulatorViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
  [DataMember]
    public ObservableCollection<Collage> ImageList
    {
        get { return this.imageList; }
        set
        {
            this.imageList = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChanged("ImageList");
        }
    }
 var storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
 var sampleFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("MyProject.Collage", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
 string l =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.ImageList);
 await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, l);
 string tres = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(l).ToString();
 this.ImageList.Clear();
 this.ImageList =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Collage>>(tres.ToString());
}


public class Collage
{
    public Thickness Position { get; set; }
    public WriteableBitmap Image { get; set; }
}
```

I have file on disk, but when I try deserialize json I have an error.
`Could not create an instance of type Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path '[0].Image.PixelBuffer', line 10, position 23.`

JSON file

```
[{"Position":{"Left":0.0,"Top":0.0,"Right":0.0,"Bottom":0.0},"Image":{"PixelBuffer":{},"PixelHeight":1600,"PixelWidth":2560,"Dispatcher":{"HasThreadAccess":true,"CurrentPriority":0}}},{"Position":{"Left":490.0,"Top":0.0,"Right":0.0,"Bottom":0.0},"Image":{"PixelBuffer":{},"PixelHeight":1600,"PixelWidth":2560,"Dispatcher":{"HasThreadAccess":true,"CurrentPriority":0}}}]
```

What`s my problem?

Comment: Can you please post the full JSON? and your Collage class too?

Comment: @sachin I updated code and added `Collage`

Comment: If you already have ImageList, why are you loading it again from the same string that you serialized it from?

Comment: @AVKNaidu because I want check it

Comment: You shouldn't be serializing WriteableBitmap objects. Save the location and the actual picture (byte array or any image format like jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      var savePicker = new FileSavePicker
            {
                SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary,
                SuggestedFileName = string.Format("MyProject{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmm"))
            };
            savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Project", new List<string> {".collage"});
            var file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
            if (file != null)
            {
                var ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.ImageList.ToList());
                await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, ser);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON file is not valid / complete.

```
[
    {
        "Position": {"Left":0.0,"Top":0.0,"Right":0.0,"Bottom":0.0},
        "Image":{
            "PixelBuffer": {},
            "PixelHeight":1600,
            "PixelWidth":2560,
            "Dispatcher":{"HasThreadAccess":true,"CurrentPriority":0}
        }
    },  <=== here it ends without a following item or closing the array.
```

You are creating a file but you are not flushing / closing it.

```
var sampleFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("MyProject.Collage",    CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
 string l =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.ImageList);
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, l); // <== no FileIO.Close(sampleFile)
```

Comment: Sorry, I copied just one part, after comma it continue

Comment: @SmiLe - have you checked if your code closes the created file before you are reading it ?

Comment: But I take data from string, not from file